# HDMI output not functioning

Tags: hdmi, retropie

the HDMI on my pi seems to be acting up, I've gotten it to boot 2/3 times after a few minutes, in the middle of configuring a controller in emulation station for example.

It's booting, my TV is recognising the HDMI input is coming from a Pi but I'm getting no signal.

I've tried different HDMI, Charging cables, Keyboards/mice. I've expanded the file system already during my initial boot (8GB class 10 SD card).

Beyond a reinstall of the OS i'm out of ideas.

Any help?

Comment: Is the HDMI cable plugged in during boot? Also, check out the [RPiconfig eLinux page](http://elinux.org/RPiconfig#Video). There are a couple settings you can mess with in the config.txt file in the boot partition that control the way video is displayed.

Comment: Yes, I agree with RPi Awesomeness.  Another thing you can do is try using RCA and see if that works.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` and `hdmi_safe=1` to the [`config.txt`](http://elinux.org/RPi_config.txt) file of the SD card. This should put the Pi into a generic video configuration that works almost all of the time.

Comment: I've already got the : # uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1 

And the:
# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

Comment: If it's still not working with those configuration settings changes, then odds are it's either a hardware issue with the Pi or a firmware issue. In the latter case a different version of Raspbian may work better.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest, firstly, looking at the the SD card compatibility list [SD Card compatibility list](http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards), especially as you mention that you've got it to boot only 2 or 3 times. I've had problems with a kingston 8gb class 10 card where mine would only boot to raspbian every so often. a new samsung card fixed that for me.

Another issue could be power? I'm not sure exactly on your configuration, you don't mention whether you have a powered usb hub for your usb devices?, it could be that the Pi is not getting enough power on it's own to fire up all connected peripherals and the HDMI.
I would try disconnecting all devices and seeing if it works then (if you haven't already)

I use retropie without any issues, but all my external devices (controller, keyboard, mouse, wifi) are powered from a externally powered usb hub.

Answer (score 1):

Something that has happened to me (Although I am a bit stupid) is there is a 'read only' switch on the SD card, which sometimes I accidentally push up, and that doesn't let it load ...